# Very different UI results on iOS with the same code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have written same code and launched it on simulator iPhone 7 with iOS 10.3 and on my iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.3 and I see some differences in there. I am sure you can see that too(the buttons are underlined, change color button has different background, etc.) [image: This is image from my iPhone 6] [image: This is image from simulator]. Why there is this difference? Can you help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's not an issue with your code. This issue is because you have switched on `Settings > General > Accessibility` Button shapes in iPhone 6.

Switch it off and the UI will become fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some of the accessibility options turn on on your  iPhone 6. It looks like "Button shapes" is turned on.